# Adicionar onclick ou Listener a um elemento que ainda não existe

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um widget externo que tem um formulário, mas não posso mudar a maneira que ele funciona (porque é proprietário). Porém eu preciso saber quando o usuário clicou nele para preencher automático alguns campos como nome e e-mail, que estão guardados na sessão do meu sistema.

Estava pensando em adicionar `elemento.addEventListener('click', inserirDados);`. 
Mas como ele é assíncrono, eu não sei quando ele vai terminar de ser carregado.  Como eu posso fazer isso? Não sei se é importante, mas tanto meu sistema quanto o widget usam apenas javascript puro.

O widget é inserido na página com:

```
(function() {
    //criação do <script>
    //configuração
    //inserção do script na página
})();
```

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Qual é o elemento teu onde o `widget` é inserido?

Comment: No final do body, com escopo global, para estar disponível em todo o sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você identifica o widget? Por um ID? Por estar dentro de algum elemento?
Se o seu widget está contido dentro de um elemento, como uma div, você pode adicionar o evento no elemento, qualquer clique nele, ou num elemento dentro dele irá disparar o evento do click.

```js
const meuWidget = document.getElementById('meuWidget');
    
//Widget é carregado assincronamente    
setTimeout(() => {
    meuWidget.innerHTML = `
    <label>Nome</label>
    <input name="nome"/>
    <label>CPF</label>
    <input name="cpf"/>
    <label>Contato</label>
    <input name="contato"/>`;
}, 3000);


meuWidget.addEventListener('click', e => {
    switch(e.target.name) {
        case "nome":
           console.log('Clicou no nome');
           break;
        case "cpf":
           console.log('Clicou no cpf');
           break;
        case "contato":
           console.log('Clicou no contato');
           break;
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="meuWidget">

</div>
```

Comment: A chamada não está dentro de uma div, pois o widget carrega a si próprio com `<script></script>` que carrega o JS mencionado na pergunta. Pelo que eu entendi, apenas colocar o <script> dentro de uma div já resolve?

Comment: Não, onde o script que carrega o seu widget está não importa, o que importa é onde o seu widget é renderizado. Qual é o elemento pai do widget? Adicione o `eventListener` nesse pai.

Comment: Mesmo não sendo a escolha considerando a navalha de Occam, sua resposta me ajudou a entender melhor o contexto além de responder a questão. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Tens de delegar esse evento noutro elemento que já exista na página. Como dizes que ele é inserido no `body` é isso mesmo que deves usar. Depois tens de verificar se o click foi dentro desse elemento ou classe:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const elemento = document.querySelector('#id-do-widget');
    if (event.target.contains(elemento)) return;
    inserirDados(event);
});
```